# Install qwt library on OS X Lion 

Tags: qt, qt4, makefile, qwt

I've downloaded qwt-6.0.1 and then tried to install qwt
. First i try to generate MakeFile :

```
qmake -spec macx-g++
```

this is ok. When i try to compile sources with `make` i get after a while

```
/bin/sh: /Developer/Tools/Qt/moc: No such file or directory
make: *** [moc/moc_qwt_dyngrid_layout.cpp] Error 127
```

From last versions ,Xcode is installed in Applications folder not in Developer ,Apple deleted this folder it can not be founded. I think here is the issue, but i do not know how to configure this, to make compile process to be successful

Can someone provide a way to install qwt on Mac ?

Answer (score 0):

The commands should be run from the qwt directory where `project.pro` is in, not in `src`.

```
stephen-mac:qwt-6.0.1 stephenc$ qmake -spec macx-g++
stephen-mac:qwt-6.0.1 stephenc$ make
...
```

Comment: i get /bin/sh: /Developer/Tools/Qt/moc: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [moc/moc_qwt_dyngrid_layout.cpp] Error 127
make: *** [sub-src-make_default-ordered] Error 2

Comment: You may need to start from scratch. Delete the qwt directory you have now and unzip a new one.